# Adding Two decimal numbers with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to update an input such that if is an integer, you add 2 zeros.

Input:  12
Output: 12.00
(In the same input-text)

```
<body ng-app="">
    <script>
    function Controller($scope) {
      $scope.change = function() {

      };
    }
  </script>
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <input type="text" ng-model="value" ng-change="change()" />
    {{value | number:2}}
  </div>
</body>
```

It could be done within $scope.change, but it would take more lines of code. 
Is there a more direct way to implement it? such as {{value | number 2}}.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've got it. Angular provides a [default filter `number`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number). It works as:

```
{{val | number:<fractionsize>}}
```

If this number will represent currency, consider using the [currency filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency).

Edit: Using a filter also probably is a good idea for maintainability of your code, as it separates getting the data from formatting it.

Comment: Hi, what I need is to automatically update the same input, but with the decimal point in the case that is an integer.

Comment: You could try binding an event to apply the number filter every time the input changes; you can use [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/R1yf6dJSf1ieYRX0B4P0?p=preview) as a starting point. However, you may notice in the example, there is some weird behavior with adding digits. Your best bet might to be writing a custom directive that handles input exactly how you're imagining.